# Texture not changing?

Tags: java

So I have a piece of code that is should to change the texture of an game object, but unfortunately for me its not working!

My treasure and blocks are not changing to what they should be!

I think a part of the problem lies in these following pieces of code:

Game.java:

```
            if(red == 255 && green == 255 & blue == 255) handler.addObject(new Block(xx*32, yy*32, 0, ObjectId.Block));

            if(red == 128 && green == 128 & blue == 128) handler.addObject(new Block(xx*32, yy*32, 1, ObjectId.Block));

            if(red == 0 && green == 0 & blue == 255) handler.addObject(new Player(xx*32, yy*32, handler, ObjectId.Player));

            if(red == 255 && green == 255 & blue == 0) handler.addObject(new Treasure(xx*32, yy*32, 0, ObjectId.Treasure));

            if(red == 255 && green == 254 & blue == 0) handler.addObject(new Treasure(xx*32, yy*32, 1, ObjectId.Treasure));
```

block:

```
    public void render(Graphics g) 
{
    if(type == 0){//dirt
        g.drawImage(tex.block[0], (int)x, (int)y, null);
    }
    if(type == 1){//grass
        g.drawImage(tex.block[1], (int)x, (int)y, null);
    }
}
```

treasure:

```
    public void render(Graphics g) {
    if(i == 0)
    {

    g.drawImage(tex.treasure[0], (int)x, (int)y, null);

    } 
    if(i == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("i = 1");
    g.drawImage(tex.treasure[1], (int)x, (int)y, null);
    }

}
```

Textures:

```
    public void render(Graphics g) {
    if(i == 0)
    {

    g.drawImage(tex.treasure[0], (int)x, (int)y, null);

    } 
    if(i == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("i = 1");
    g.drawImage(tex.treasure[1], (int)x, (int)y, null);
    }

}
```

So these are the parts of my code which I think are causing the problem. Also, `i` and `type` have been declared earlier in the code, I just did not include those parts.

Comment: what are the 'i' and 'type' variables ? my guess is the problem is in the code where those values change, can you post it ? just a wild guess, but i think the problem is their scope, maybe they should be parameters of the render methods

Comment: if(red == 128 && green == 128 & blue == 128) handler.addObject(new Block(xx*32, yy*32, 1, ObjectId.Block)); its the 1/0 in the level code

Comment: by the way, its not relevant to your question but you're mixing shotcircuit(&&) and regular(&) AND's in the same expression. if(red == 128 && green == 128 & blue == 128)

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten this:

```
type = type;
```